# Batch/bulk insert/update modelized data

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

I want to speed up the insert operation,

Because I have billions of data to insert,

So I tried to temporarily store the data in @bulk_data

and insert it in the last step, `model.collection.insert(@bulk_data)`

But I got `NoMethodError: undefined method 'to_bson' for`,

Because I use dynamic attributes,  So I could not simply store each data in hash

```
LOOP BEGIN
@bulk_data = []
new_data = model.capitalize.constantize.new
new_data.title = ...
@bulk_data << new_data
....
LOOP END

model.collection.insert(@bulk_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

> Because I use dynamic attributes, So I could not simply store each data in hash

This is not true. You should have no problem generating keys dynamically for your hash.

Anyway, to solve your `'to_bson'` error you should simply call `as_document` on your model when you are inserting it into your `@bulk_data` array. Like so:

```
@bulk_data << new_data.as_document
```

As a side note, for speeding up your inserts you should make sure that you do not have a large set of indexes to maintain. And of course make sure that you are not running any type of existence validation since that would effectively cause a the code to `find` every time you want to `insert`.